# Xamarin Forms ImageButton - image not showing

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, imagebutton

Currently using the Xamarin.Forms.Labs library and when I use ImageButton, only the text appears and not the image:

```
var bttn = new ImageButton {
                BackgroundColor = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Transparent,
                Text = "Button",
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                Source = "image.png",
                Orientation = Xamarin.Forms.Labs.Enums.ImageOrientation.ImageToLeft,
                ImageHeightRequest = 50,
                ImageWidthRequest = 50,
                WidthRequest = 150,
                HeightRequest = 150,
            };
```

Why is it not showing the image?

Answer (score 2):

I have run across this issue and it drove me crazy! This is how you go about fixing it. Let me know if this helps you out.

**iOS** : Make sure you added the necessary implementation within the **AppDelegate.cs** file. Just replace what you currently have with the following and make sure you are **using** Xamarin.Forms.Labs.iOS

```
`public partial class AppDelegate : XFormsApplicationDelegate`
```

**Android** : Make sure you added the necessary implementation within the **MainActivity.cs** file. Just replace what you currently have with the following and make sure you are **using** Xamarin.Forms.Labs.Droid

```
`public class MainActivity : XFormsApplicationDroid`
```

Answer (score 1):

If the resource image is named my_image.png then you would use the property Image="my_image":

```
var leftMenuButton = new Xamarin.Forms.Labs.Controls.ImageButton 
{
    Image="my_image",
    ImageHeightRequest = 10,
    BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
    BorderColor = Color.Black
};
```